# Singular solution of profiles equidistant from parabola

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

Circles radius $R$ drawn on parabola

$$ (x-2 at)^2+(y-at^2)^2=R^2\tag1$$

Differentiating with respect to $t$ and simplifying we get

$$  -4ax+ 8a^2t-4ya t +4a^2t^3=0; \rightarrow t^3+t(2-y/a)-x/a =0 \tag2$$

How can we now eliminate $t$ between third and and fourth order equations 1) and 2)?

Goebner basis could be applied I guess but how is it actually done? Two solutions are expected and how do they come about in the elimination?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Are you after the offset curve of the parabola ?

Comment: Yes after a DE of two curves on either side of the parabola.

Answer (score 0):

The offset curve at distance $d$ can be found as the locus of the tip of a normal vector of length $d$.

$$x=2at,y=at^2\to\vec n=\pm\frac{2ad}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}(t,-1),$$ giving the parametric equations

$$x=2at\pm\frac{2ad}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}t,\\y=at^2\mp\frac{2ad}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}.$$

Elimination of $t$ doesn't seem easy.

---

Have a look at the incredible "[Brief atlas of offset curves](https://documat.unirioja.es/descarga/articulo/3217873.pdf)".

Comment: Thanks, Yves Daoust. I hoped to get $ F(x,y)$ or its DE form in order to write the curve coordinates with uniform increments of $x$ or arc.The DE of singular solution would be also helpful.

Comment: For uniform increments, you can (have to) numerically integrate the parametric equation.

Comment: Or perhaps find DE of singular solution and integrate it?